# Перевод столбца в строки

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, pivot

Работаю с файлом, загруженным в Jupyter Notebook, использую в основном Pandas.

Есть таблица ([данные в файле CSV](https://dropmefiles.com/GFHUN)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество продуктов у одного покупателя не ограничено.

Необходимо получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовала и `merch`, и `pivot`, но, видимо, моих знаний пока не достаточно.

Comment: Добавьте нужные метки. Что это, excel, БД какая-то? Укажите используемую питоновскую библиотеку также

Comment: Это  файл, загруженный в Jupyter. excel для примера. Использую Pandas.

Comment: Вы можете привести воспроизводимый пример исходных данных?

Comment: Выложила небольшой пример в csv, подойдет? https://dropmefiles.com/GFHUN

Comment: вам нужно, чтобы каждый продукт был в отдельном столбце?

Comment: Да, в отдельном

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .assign(x=df.groupby("customer").cumcount()+1)
       .pivot(index="customer", columns="x", values="product")
       .add_prefix("product_")
       .rename_axis(None)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

результат:

```
In [16]: res
Out[16]:
  product_1 product_2 product_3 product_4 product_5 product_6 product_7
a     apple     lemon       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
b      kiwi     apple       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
c    grapes     lemon       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
d    banana     apple      kiwi     lemon     melon       NaN       NaN
e    banana      kiwi     melon       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
f      plum     melon      pear     mango    orange    banana      kiwi
```